# How to change internal table properties

Tags: css

If I want to treat the properties of a table imbedded in a cell differently than the outer table, what is required. I am new to CSS and do not have a handle on the cascading effect. A boiled downed example of my attempt is as follows:

```
<body>
<table><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="OuterTable.css">
    <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <table><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="InnerTable.css"><tr><th>InsideColA1</th><th>InsideColA2</th></tr></table>
    </td>
    <td>
            <table><tr><th>InsideColB1</th><th>InsideColB2</th></tr></table>
    </td>
    </tr>            
</table>
</b
```

Where the OuterTable.css specifies a pink background for the  cells and InnerTable.css specifies yellow for the  cells. Obviosuly, I am missing something basic as all header styles have a yellow background. What is the best method for styling an internal table.

Comment: You should study some basic CSS tutorials since this is not the right approach to style nested elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Add class(*inner and outer as shown below*) to your table

b) remove your CSS file from table and add to head

c) just add the below style statements to your css.

```
<style type="text/css">
   table.outer {
     background-color:yellow
    }
  table.outer th {
      // add style properties here
   }
   table.inner {
       background-color:pink
   }
  table.inner th {
     // add style properties here
   }
</style>

<table class="outer">
   <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th></tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="inner"><tr><th>InsideColA1</th><th>InsideColA2</th></tr></table>
   </td>
   <td>
        <table><tr><th>InsideColB1</th><th>InsideColB2</th></tr></table>
   </td>
  </tr>            
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First, don't import CSS at the middle of your HTML code, put it on the `<head>` tag please.
2. You can style your HTML elements by "id" or "class", I'll make and example using class, check it:

   ```
   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="OuterTable.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="InnerTable.css">

   <style>

   .outerTable{
       background-color:#FF0000;
   }    

   .innerTable{
       background-color:#FF00FF;
   } 
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <table class="outerTable">
    <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th></tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <table class="innerTable"><tr><th>InsideColA1</th><th>InsideColA2</th></tr></table>
       </td>
       <td>
           <table><tr><th>InsideColB1</th><th>InsideColB2</th></tr></table>
       </td>
      </tr>            
     </table>
   </body>
   ```

Instead the class at `<style>` tag, you put your code at your .css files

see it working at: http://jsfiddle.net/U5cUK/

Answer (score 0):

First off, all CSS files should be included in the `<head>` of your HTML document.

Now, if you want to target a nested table, all you have to do is use a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) like this:

```
/*Define default color for cells*/
table th{
    background-color: pink; 
}
/*Override for headers inside a nested table*/
table table th{
    background-color: yellow; 
}
```

No need for a separate CSS file or custom classes or ids

See **[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/L6wxD/)**